# QuoteDocument, convert data from document field to pdf

Tags: pdf, quote

I've been trying for days to access the quote's PDF file from an external site linked to my org with heroku connect, I was finally able to retrieve data from QuoteDocument Object [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_quotedocument.htm).
It says at the documentation that the value in document field is base64 type, the binary data for the PDF file. But when I try and decode the value of that field to PDF format using [base64 to PDF decoder](https://base64.guru/converter/decode/pdf) and other conversion sites I get an unreadable file.
[image]

[image]

I have tried with multiple files but the problem is the same, does anyone know how to retrieve the PDF binary data or the PDF file source itself from Salesforce or QuoteDocument Object to be able to view it?

Comment: Could be the way PDF was generated, could be the decoder. Try storing the PDF in `QuoteDocument` via the platform based on this [example](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/347441/quote-pdf-generated-by-automated-process-missing-fields) then troubleshoot from there.

Comment: @identigral thank you for answering, the problem is not with the actual content of the pdf because i can access it and view it from the quote record page, what i want to do is retrieve where it's stored so i could use it outside of salesforce without having to go through the quote record or salesforce UI.